# How can I go through web pages by providing my log in details and get the required data automatically?

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am new to programming and would like to know how to go to a website by giving the log in credentials, and selecting one element from a drop down and get the required data from that web page, everything automatically by running a script.

Comment: You will need to give us an example of code you have done already and we can then point you in the right direction/give you advice.

Comment: We ain't going to write it for you.  Even if there was enough detail to allow us.  This is not a "we do your programming for free" site.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, SO is not a coding service. However, here are some pointers to get you started:

- Selenium Java API
- PhantomJS
- JSoup
- Java Webcrawler

Just type the above keywords in your favorite search engine and you'll quickly find good starters.